# How can I change 2.5E7 to a normally formatted number?

Tags: java

How can I change 2.5E7 to 2,500,000.00?

Comment: Can you give more details?  How did you get it in scientific notation to begin with?  Is it in a string or some other datatype?  A little code snippet would be nice.

Comment: I honestly have no idea it got into scientific notation. Originally when I downloaded the data it was 2500000.00. Right now it is in a String. I can make it an int if thats easier.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not confusing a numeric value with the String representation of the number? Again, some code will go a long way towards making your question answerable.  As it stands you give us precious little to go on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#0,0000.00");
String formattedNumber = format.format(number);
```

[See here](http://ideone.com/JJbvH)

If you are trying to parse 2.5E7 then you can do this

```
long number = Double.valueOf("2.5E7").longValue();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's trying to parse a number, not format one.

Comment: @Kyle The question is not very clear but I added an edit to parse as well.

Comment: well I was trying to do both. This helped me a lot. I was just doing something silly and completely forgot to make the int a long, so I made it a string, which still didn't work. Thanks!