# error parsing double java

Tags: java, string, selenium, double

I have this code:

```
public void refreshResources(){
    try{
        String res = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#resources_metal")).getText();
        System.out.println("Metal read: " + res);
        res = res.replaceAll("\\u002e", ""); //Removes dots
        System.out.println("Metal without dots: " + res);
        this.metRes = Double.parseDouble(res);
        System.out.println("Converted Metal: " + metRes);
    }catch(NoSuchElementException error){
        System.out.println("Error please try again");
    }
```

This is my output:

Metal read: 47.386.578

Metal without dots: 47386578

Converted Metal: 4.7386578E7

the question is, why do I have that "E7" at the end of my converted metal?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: suppose you refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171823/how-can-i-change-2-5e7-to-a-normally-formatted-number).

Comment: A double doesn't have infinite precision. That is your value in scientific notation.

Comment: This will give you a lot of background around the "why" question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Seriously guys thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

the "Ex" where "x" is a number, means Exponential. So in your case, the number "4.7386578E7" will be "47386578". Just take right the dot 7 places.

However, if you want to print the number with no exponential notation, you can use "printf" in the last print, just like the next code:

```
public void refreshResources(){
try{
    String res = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#resources_metal")).getText();
    System.out.println("Metal read: " + res);
    res = res.replaceAll("\\u002e", ""); //Removes dots
    System.out.println("Metal without dots: " + res);
    this.metRes = Double.parseDouble(res);
    System.out.printf("Converted Metal: %.0f", metRes);
}catch(NoSuchElementException error){
    System.out.println("Error please try again");
}
```

%.0f means that you want to print a float value with no decimal part.

I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of primitive double or float use "BigDecimal" of "java.math" package. This will give you more precise output. Please see the snippet used below.

```
try{
    String res = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#resources_metal")).getText();
    System.out.println("Metal read: " + res);
    res = res.replaceAll("\\u002e", ""); //Removes dots
    System.out.println("Metal without dots: " + res);
    this.metRes = Double.parseDouble(res);
    System.out.printf("Converted Metal: %.0f", metRes);
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(res);
    System.out.println("Big Decimal : "+bigDecimal);
}catch(NoSuchElementException error){
    System.out.println("Error please try again");
}
```