# Need help in converting some values in my SQL Table Column to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Varchar column which have data such as 1.025407162E7, 1.268479084E7 basically it contains something called as E7. How can i convert it to decimal ?

I have tried to convert it to decimal, I could have removed the E7 and moved the decimal point 7 steps forward or Add 7 zeros if there are no so many numbers. But I was looking for a right approach to do it.

`CONVERT(DECIMAL(27, 7), ETL_AM.BNK_SHR_LGR_BAL_AMT)`

So the actual values look different

```
1.025407162E7 = 10254071.6200000 and 1.268479084E7 = 12684790.8400000
```

Comment: This is scientific notation. It's not great database design to be storing this as a character. In any case - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750021/casting-scientific-notation-from-varchar-numeric-in-a-view

Comment: Is this similar to what you are looking to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171823/how-can-i-change-2-5e7-to-a-normally-formatted-number

Comment: Is this similar to what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171823/how-can-i-change-2-5e7-to-a-normally-formatted-number

Comment: It looks like the conversion worked pretty well, what is the problem?

Comment: Is this similar to what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171823/how-can-i-change-2-5e7-to-a-normally-formatted-number

Comment: @Alohajoe5 no need to keep posting the comment over and over. Also that question is about how to do this in java, this question is about sql server.

Comment: @Alohajoe5 No, that is Java, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

That's a valid [`float` constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#float-and-real-constants) for SQL Server.  So convert the string to a float, and then to a decimal.

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(27, 7), cast(ETL_AM.BNK_SHR_LGR_BAL_AMT as float))
```

eg

```
select convert(decimal(27,7), cast( '1.025407162E7' as float) )
```

returns

```
10254071.6200000
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So Error_2646 has taken me in right direction. I converted the value to REAL then converted to decimal.

```
CASE WHEN SF_FAM.FinServ__Balance__c like '%E%' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(27, 7), CONVERT(float(27), SF_FAM.FinServ__Balance__c))
ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(27, 7), SF_FAM.FinServ__Balance__c) END
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an exponential function, a simple select, after converting it to a float can give you the decimal.

```
SELECT CAST('1.025407162E7' AS FLOAT)
```

Otherwise, if E is a random character and if you want to do the calculatoin, you can do it using a case statement.

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(100) 
SET @value =  '1.025407162E7'
SELECT CASE WHEN @value like '%E7%' 
THEN (1.025407162 * 10000000)
END
```